# adding 32-bit aligned values result in 32-bit aligned?

Tags: c, alignment

Would it be correct to say that adding 32-bit aligned values produce 32-bit aligned? Assuming that a 32-bit aligned number would have 2 minor bits set to 0, I'd say yes.

Comment: if possible can someone enlight us about aligned values ?

Comment: If the sun shines, is the sun shining? Not clear what you actually ask. A value does not have an alignment.

Comment: @Mark, I would suggest revising your question, even though there are four answers with assumptions about what you intended. Correcting the question will make it clear for anyone coming across this later.

Answer (score 3):

"Values" are not aligned, variables are.

But if you add two integer types that are 32 bits wide, the resulting expression will also be 32 bit.  What the exact type will be depends on the actual types of the operands.

If what you mean is whether or not two values representing an address with a 32 bit alignment will produce the same , the answer is yes, assuming 8 bits per bytes.

Such a value is divisible by 4 so it has the form `4*x` .  So if you have two such values, adding them gives you `4*a + 4*b == 4*(a+b)`.  So the result is also divisible by 4.

Note however that it is not legal to add two pointers.  You can however add an integer value to a pointer.

Comment: Your math makes so much more sense than mine. I've been dealing in bits so long that I sometimes overlook the much simpler arithmetic to represent the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be correct to say that adding 32-bit aligned values produce 32-bit aligned? Assuming that a 32-bit aligned number would have 2 minor bits set to 0, I'd say yes.

No, it is not correct, because alignment is a characteristic of *storage*, not of values.

Comment: what is exactly storage alignment ?

Comment: @rondino, the fundamental characteristics of a block of storage are its (starting) address and its size.  A piece of storage is aligned on a 32-bit boundary if its address, in bits, is a multiple of 32.  Ordinarily, however, we express addresses and count in 8-bit units, in which terms the criterion is that the address is a multiple of 4.

Answer (score 2):

Working on the assumption that you mean 32-bit aligned addresses...

If an integer variable `addrA` contains a 32-bit aligned address, that means bits 0 and 1 are set to 0. If the same is true of `addrB` then the resulting addition, regardless of the upper bits, will also have bits 0 and 1 set to 0.

So, making some assumptions about what you mean, yes, adding these two address that are 32-bit aligned will always result in a 32-bit aligned address.

In addition, since I have assumed that you were referring to addresses, another thing to consider is that if you are operating on pointers, two pointers cannot be added. If one is a pointer and one is an integer, then [pointer arithmetic](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) will be used.

Comment: You may have caught the OP's intent, but you cannot add pointers in C.  (Pointer + integer, yes, but not two pointers.)

Answer (score 0):

Operator `+` doesn't produce a memory object, There is no point to talk about result alignment.